# How to fill the background from the illustration with color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, background, fill

I would like to place this illustration over an image with a black background. Firstly I want to fill the transparent background inside of the illustration with the white color. How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select everything, and click *Object > Live Paint > Make*

Choose the Live Paint Bucket, set white as the background colour.

Click inside the gap to fill the areas you want.